# Chromium single executable build

Tags: chromium, ubuntu-18.04

I've been following the documentation [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md) to build Chromium on Ubuntu 18.

I've been able to successfully build using these flags `gn gen out/amd64 --args='is_official_build=true is_debug=false'`

and this command to build

`autoninja -C out/amd64 chrome`

The problem is that the outputting chrome file has dependencies on all the other files in the directory. When I copy the chrome file to another directory and execute it, I get this error

`[0608/170138.585281:ERROR:icu_util.cc(165)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

How do I go about building Chromium so I can execute it from a single file like how Puppeteer is a single executable?

Comment: As you are building your own Chromium, you should read this build file: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/BUILD.gn?q=chrome.dll+file:%5Esrc/+package:%5Echromium$&g=0&l=64

Comment: I've asked the exact same question over at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149677/chromium-single-executable-build as this is actually specific to Ubuntu.

@Asesh The link you provided seems to be for Windows builds, not Ubuntu. The build.gn that I have checked out doesn't give me any insight as to how to build as a single binary.